# How to test time equality in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the next query:

```
UPDATE flights, airlines 
SET flights.business_booked_seats = flights.business_booked_seats + 3 
WHERE flights.airline_id = airlines.id 
AND airlines.name = EasyJet 
AND flights.origin_airport = London 
AND flights.destination_airport = Tokyo 
AND flights.departingDate = 2014-04-16 
AND flights.arrival_date = 2014-04-17 
AND flights.departing_time = 11:30:00 
AND flights.arrival_time = 04:00:00
```

and I get

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':30:00 AND flights.arrival_time = 04:00:00' at line 1
```

I also tried `TIME(11:30:00)` but it didn't work.

The structure of the tables is the following:

`Airlines[id(int), name(varchar)]`

`Flights[origin_airport(varchar), destination_airport(varchar), departing_date(date), arrival_date(date), departing_time(time), arrival_time(time), economy_capacity(int), business_capacity(int), economy_booked_seats(int), business_booked_seats(int), economy_price(decimal), business_price(decimal), airline_id(int)]`

How can I write the query correctly?

Comment: _It must be an airport game for children, isn't it?_

Comment: no... it is a project with the JADE platform for Java... and the personal assistant agent has to book plane tickets

Comment: Can you please tell us more about your tables? DESC flights; DESC airlines; It'll help answering your question, thanks.

Comment: And well, the problem is that the code is placed in pre and overflow-x become scroll. There is no method that you can make the code tidier.

Comment: Why don't you use departing_datetime(datetime) and arrival_datetime(datetime) instead?

Comment: it's too late now... it's 1 a.m. here and at the deadline is 10 a.m... I want to go to sleep :))

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru Welcome to the life of a programmer. Sleep is for the weak. :)

Comment: I do feel a bit weak :)). Good night! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, using `datetime` types would probably make more sense. With that out of the way, you want to wrap your time literals in single quotes. `'11:30:00'`

`TIME()` won't do it - it takes an *expression* as a parameter, which 11:30:00 isn't, but `TIME '11:30:00'` would redundantly accomplish the same thing as just leaving it there in single quotes.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

And since I can't comment due to reputation, I'll add here that using STR_TO_DATE is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to respect the SQL format.

All strings are between quotes (double or single), so you'll need:

```
AND airlines.name = 'EasyJet'
AND flights.origin_airport = 'London'
AND flights.destination_airport = 'Tokyo'
```

And you can convert strings into dates and times with `STR_TO_DATE` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
AND flights.departingDate = STR_TO_DATE('2014-04-16','%Y-%m-%d')
AND flights.arrival_date = STR_TO_DATE('2014-04-17','%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or you can compare the strings:

```
AND flights.departingDate = '2014-04-16'
AND flights.arrival_date '2014-04-17'
AND flights.departing_time = '11:30:00'
AND flights.arrival_time = '04:00:00'
```

Addendum: `STR_TO_DATE` will be useful to you if you work with another format that is not `YYYY-MM-DD`. It works here without `STR_TO_DATE` because you were nice enough to provide the date in that format, but other formats (like the usual English `MM/DD/YYYY` won't match automatically).